# Force no-backslash except on specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What I want to do is remove any end backslash of a URL, except! if the folder is the folder 'batman' or any sub folder of it, such as 'batman/robin', then I want to force! a backslash.

```
Example 1: www.example.com/batman -> www.example.com/batman/
Example 2: www.example.com/batman/robin -> www.example.com/batman/robin/
Example 3: www.example.com/spiderman/ -> www.example.com/spiderman
```

I got the following code, but I cant get it to work:

```
RewriteEngine on

# add trailing slash when url is /batman
RewriteRule ^v$ /batman/ [R=301,L]

#remove trailing slash (ignore batman)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/batman/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: removed it, didnt help :/

Comment: Show your complete .htaccess in question. Then provide a URL that you tried and didn't work